# Overflow while bit shifting in java

Tags: java, long-integer, integer-overflow

I have situation which I dont undestand.
When I do

```
 System.out.println(1<<30);
```

I got very big positive number 1073741824.
But when I do

```
 System.out.println(1<<31);
```

I got very low number -2147483648.
As I read long type is signed 64 bit long. Max number is 2^63 -1. So here I dont undestand why my shift goes negative((((
Doing

```
System.out.println((long)(1<<31));
```

also gives the same result(((

Comment: Why did you think the numbers here would be `long` ?

Comment: Yep, you are right. But why System.out.println((long)(1<<31)); does not work either???

Comment: because you're casting too late, when it's already MIN_VALUE. See the answer, it's right.

Comment: Because you cast the result (an int) not the operands. The expression (1<<31) is already an integer.

Comment: Thank you, very much. Very interesting situation for me. I created 100 tests for my little program and 1 of 100 didnt pass. Now I see why. Spent a day to catch it)))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`1 << 31` is an int, not a long. And what you have is not really an overflow, but `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (sign bit set, all the rest zeroes).

Unless you suffix them appropriately, any numeric constant in Java is an `int` by default. If you want a long, you have to tell the compiler that you want a long: `1L << 31` (**note the `L`**).

And note that even `(long) (1 << 31)` wouldn't work; even in this scenario, `1 << 31` remains an int. Casting "after the fact" doesn't help ;)

Answer (score 0):

When we shift 1 by 31 to the left we get 0x80000000, this is Integer.MIN_VALUE = -2147483648. See Integer class.